# How to resize a dynamically allocated array inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, resize, allocation

I have a private array inside a class, allocated dynamically. As I insert more and more items, I need to resize the array at some point. The question is how to do that correctly? The code below ends in an error: *munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer* while inserting a third item.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Set
{
private:
    T * array;
    size_t arraySize;
    unsigned int itemCount;

public:

    Set() {
        arraySize = 1;
        itemCount = 0;
        array = new T[arraySize];
    };

    bool Insert(const T item) {
        if (itemCount == arraySize) {
            T * tmpArray = new T[arraySize * 2];
            memcpy(tmpArray, array, arraySize * sizeof(T));
            arraySize *= 2;
            delete [] array;
            array = tmpArray;
        }

        array[itemCount] = item;
        itemCount++;
        return true;
    }

};

int main ()
{
    Set<string> x0;
    assert( x0 . Insert( "apple" ) );
    assert( x0 . Insert( "orange" ) );
    assert( x0 . Insert( "pineapple" ) );
    return 0;
}
```

I know I could use for example a vector to don't care about the allocation, but I would like to know how to do that properly this way.

Please forgive, if the question is somehow inappropriate. It is my first time questioning

Comment: Create a new larger array; copy the contents of old to new; delete old; assign new array to member variable.

Comment: Before "first time questioning", you should've taken the [tour], read the [help], learn [ask] questions, and, most importantly, understand the ***mandatory requirements*** for a [mre]. Did you do all of this? The shown code fails to meet all requirements for a [mre]. There are multiple reasons for the shown code to result in undefined behavior and memory corruption. Without a [mre], it's not possible to authoritatively tell you the actual reason (possibly all of them).

Comment: @RichardCritten That's basically what I did, isn't it ?

Comment: `memcpy` only works for trivially copyable types; you should copy element by element.

Comment: Is it an exercise or do you want something that works _out of the box_? `std::vector<T>`  may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay, thanks. I edited it to make the problem reproducible at least

Comment: Ok, definitely avoid `memcpy`. And don't forget the destructor.

Comment: @RichardCritten The did solve the problem. Thank you :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I want to avoid STL containers.

Comment: @MatG Yes, avoiding ```memcpy``` solved the problem :-)

Comment: @MikerowaveOven Now proceed: use initializers list in constructor, use a smart pointer or implement the destructor, copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, work on exception safety pitfalls in `Insert`, armonize your adopted integer types, avoid useless postfix ++ operator, then throw it all away and use `std::vector` :-)

Comment: @MatG Yes, this is exactly the scenario that I am following right know. And at the end I will throw it all away and use vectors instead :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the commenters said, plus the fact that you can replace your `memcpy` with a call to [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to get the correct behaviour:

```
std::copy (array, array + arraySize, tmpArray);
```

Don't forget to `#include <algorithm>`.